# What is " x– direction " and " y-direction "?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology, mathematics, example

It is related with mathematics and cartesian plane.I want to know what " x-direction " and " y-direction " is .it will be better if you explain it with an example.

Comment: Do you understand what a [cartesian co-ordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) is? If so, it should be obvious that "x-direction" is aligned with the x-axis of a coordinate system and, likewise, "y-direction" is aligned with the y-axis of that coordinate system

Answer (score 2):

One method of saying x-direction is left-right; y-direction would be up-down; there is also variation of this same thing: "left or right" , "left and right" / "up or down" , "up and down".

Also, one could use "horizontal" for x-direction, and "vertical" for y-direction.

Comment: Hello. Nick. This is not suitable for ELU, belonging properly on Mathematics.SE or Mathematics Educators.SE (and possibly too basic, without research shown, on that site). // Note that 'vertical' is used for 'straight up and down the paper' even when the paper being used (it still happens) is in the horizontal plane, and 'horizontal' reserved for 'straight across the paper' as I'm sure you're aware; this peculiarity needs pointing out to people learning the subject.

Comment: The y-direction is normally "up" a page, but the page may be lying horizontally. The z-direction is unambiguously vertically upwards. In any case I don't think this question belongs here but in Maths